# Set_Weights in NLTK Maxent?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I'm wondering what the set_weights method of the Maxent class in NLTK is used for (or more specifically how to use it). As I understand, it allows you to manually assign weights to certain features? Could somebody provide a basic example of the type of parameter that would be passed into it?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It apparently allows you to set the coefficient matrix of the classifier. This may be useful if you have an external MaxEnt/logistic regression learning package from which you can export the coefficients. The `train_maxent_classifier_with_gis` and `train_maxent_classifier_with_iis` learning algorithms call this function.

If you don't know what a coefficient matrix is; it's the β mentioned in [Wikipedia's treatment of MaxEnt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logit#Model).

(To be honest, it looks like NLTK is either leaking implementation details here, or has a very poorly documented API.)